# Why does my stored procedure execute all selects regardless of condition logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, logic

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have an interesting scenario where a stored procedure (written by a "power user") has an okay runtime of (around 4 seconds) if there's data in the primary table. If the search value doesn't exist, the run time averages out at about 3 minutes. Because of how the process works, and the web application that uses the procedure, it requires an empty result set in the case of no data.

I've tested the logic below with values that have data and values that don't and the flow seems to work; however, when I put my actual query in the else statement, it seems like that part is always being evaluated despite my knowing that logic branch shouldn't execute.

```
DECLARE @spId int

SELECT @spId = td.mainId
FROM dbo.PRIMARYTABLE
WHERE td.longId = @searchVal

IF @spId < 1 OR @spId IS NULL
BEGIN
     select 'RETURN EMPTY RESULT SET' as test
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'DO ACTUAL QUERY' as test
END
```

When I test this with a dummy value, such as 1111, the select 'RETURN EMPTY RESULT SET' as test is returned. When I use a value that I know exists, the SELECT 'DO ACTUAL QUERY' as test is returned. When I replace "SELECT 'DO ACTUAL QUERY' as test" with the actual heavy duty query and use the same non-existent dummy value, it still looks like the ELSE clause is reached.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You said "looks like", so you are not sure? Also, what is your "heavy duty" query? the code you posted is not complete (e.g. missing alias, variable declaration), so it might be you do something different with your "heavy duty" query. I **doubt** you hit ELSE clause with non-satisfying criteria

Comment: The "heavy duty" query is a monstrosity with Casts, Round, & IsNulls used throughout for a number of calculations. I don't know if there's a Sql Server stored procedure mechanic I'm not familiar with, but in my testing, the if/else condition logic appeared sound; however, it still seems like the else portion is called when executed from code (either through sql management studio or asp.net mvc web application).

Comment: just replacing "light-weight" Select with "havy duty" one would not change the IF...ELSE flow. It is most likely your IF condition (read @spId variable) that gets "unexpected value". Nikola's answer can provide you a good starting point to look at. **The last thing** would be to think that with *@spId < 1 or null* you somehow can hit ELSE block.

Comment: I defaulted @spId to 0 after declaring it and added @@rowcount to the condition. I added print statements and I've executed the guts of the stored procedure in sql server management studio. This is bizarre. The correct logic branch is being executed; however, that logic is nothing more than (quite literally) select '' as col1, '' as col2, '' as col3. Executing that by itself is under a second; it should be a near costless thing; however, it still takes about 3 minutes to run, which is how long the big query takes when given a searchVal that doesn't exist. I am utterly baffled here.

Comment: Sorry... I would just ask you to post the **whole** thing (code) in here. Like, "hey, this code ... works fine", and "this one ... does not. Why?".

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-sql-servers-with-recompile-option/5662581). It seems that `with recompile` option might be right choice for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are not showing everything. There is an counter-intuitive thing about assignment in select where no rows are returned - the value of variable will not be cleared. Paste this in SSMS:

```
declare @searchVal as int
set @searchVal=111

DECLARE @spId int
set @spId = 2134
SELECT @spId = td.mainId
FROM (select 839 as mainId, 0 as longid) td
where td.longId = @searchVal
print @spid
```

@spid will be 2134. This is why you should always test using @@rowcount, in you case

```
IF @@rowcount = 0 or @spId < 1 or @spId is null
BEGIN
    select 'RETURN EMPTY RESULT SET' as test
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'DO ACTUAL QUERY' as test
END
```

There is also a possibility of duplicated data by longId, returning random mainid from rows that satisfy @searchval condition.

Other than that, I would not know.

Comment: Changing the select to `select @spId = max(td.MainId)` would also work, because then one row is always returned, and is null in the case of no matching record found. If `longId` has a unique constraint, SQL Server should generate a plan that looks up the one value by the associated index.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I apologize for the lack of posting the entire stored procedure, but I'm not allowed to share that exact code. The snippet I began with was psuedo code (well, real code with tables and fields renamed).

I think Nikola Markovinović may be onto something with his answer and article link. This entire ordeal has been sort of maddening. I googled, debugged, and did the whole thing again, then search on stack overflow. After a few changes from your suggestions, the procedure magically started responding with the run time I thought it should. I don't think some of the initial changes took or maybe they weren't be cached by sql server correctly; I've got nothing but guesses.

It's very strange because, for a good hour or more, it was running as if it had never been changed (performance wise)...then it just kicked into gear. I wonder if this isn't my fault and maybe I didn't alter the one on staging like I did the one on Test...that seems the most feasible explanation.

Anyhow, thank you for your suggestions. I've learned a few things so that's always good.